# Automation of GIT repo sync, get older commit versions, verify version

Tags: android, git, version-control, commit

I'm very new at GIT, apologize if this is a basic question however I couldn't seem to find a similar situation after searching google and stackoverflow. Here's my scenario:
I have a git folder with the latest commit version that I do NOT perform any commit (I won't do any changes in the code in my local directory). Other people performs the commit on their computer, I just need to get a specific commit version, copy it to a working directory and build code. I'm planning to make a program to automatically perform these steps in repeated cycle everyday. Steps summarized below:

1. Get the latest commit in repo_folder
2. Go back to old commit version
3. Copy to a work_folder
4. Then build code in work_folder

I'm not sure if these steps are the correct/best way to do it. Also, how can I perform #2 correctly and how to make sure my program have retrieved the correct commit version? Is #3 necessary? Or can I just build code directly in repo_folder (might modify some files after build), then afterwards perform git command to get the latest commit version again?

Here's my steps actual steps

## 1. Get the latest commit in repo_folder

> repo init -u ssh://username@git.aaa.com:1234/manifest.git -b branch -m file.xml
>
> repo sync

After getting to the latest repo, I search through the logs and perform git reset --hard

## 2. Go back to old commit version

> cd .repo/manifests
>
> COMMITHASH=`git log --grep=$keyword | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2`
>
> git reset --hard $COMMITHASH
>
> cp file.xml new_file.xml
>
> repo init -m new_file.xml

After this command, I'm not sure how to check if my current version is correct.

Steps 3 and 4 just simple copy and build commands not related to this question.

> cp -r repo_folder/folder1 work_folder/folder1
>   cp -r repo_folder/folder2 work_folder/folder2
>   run build.bat

Comment: `repo init -m new_file.xml` what is this supposed to do? `init` has no `-m` option

Comment: It will select manifest files in the repository.  http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html

Answer (score 0):

Just `clone` your local master to a new directory and then `checkout` to the version that you currently need in that one:

No copying, no mucking about.

```
git clone -l /path/to/master /path/to/working
cd /path/to/working
git checkout -f REV_OR_BRANCH_ID
```

*If you have any generated files such as objects it is a good idea to clean them up - such as with `make clean` after a checkout.*

from then on you can:

```
cd /path/to/working
git pull
git checkout -f REV_OR_BRANCH_ID
```